# android activity keep running after calling finish()

Tags: android

In splash activity I want to exit app when calling `onStop()` (**I want to stop app if user clicks home button , Close screen or press backbutton**)

Unfortunately calling `finish()` didn't help , even after exiting app the splash activity continue working and even starts the next activity

I would like to mention that there is an asynctask class inside splash.activity and there is also another class `jsonfetch` called in splash.activity ( fetch data from server and open next activity after ) I think this one doesnt stop because when exiting app it opens the next activity after few secondes

Comment: I think you're leaking context somewhere, and when the network calls finish, they still have the context in memory and start next activity. Can't you just dispose your calls in `onStop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests I found that System.exit(0); fixed the problem for me , I hope this solution helps anyone that has the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are navigating to your MainActivity from you SplashActivity.

Try adding a global variable shouldNavigate to your SplashActivity and change it to false if onStop() is called;

```
private boolean shouldNavigate = true

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        shouldNavigate = false;
        super.onStop();   
        finish();
    }
```

And then do a check when navigating to your MainActivity:

```
if (shouldNavigate){
     // navigate to MainActivity
}
```

Comment: Don't you think this is a workaround/dirty fix to a problem that OP is having ?

Comment: It's the only solution i could suggest without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using countdowntimer in splash activity, then please stop that in `onStop()`. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
System.exit(0);
try{ 
    finish();
    //code  press backbutton 
    }catch(Exception  e){
}
finally{  //inside  
    System.exit(0);
}
```